# charging animation for android

Tags: android, android-animation, battery

Hi I'm customizing an android phone-tablet 7" android 4.0.4 and I would like to know how can I change the charging animation and where it is located...any ideas where the generic android have those? Thanks I'd appreciate any help. Actually I have changed all of those: 
the boot_logo, the bootanimation, the battery.bmp and the low_battery.bmp so I was wondering if there exist something like charging_animation.zip or charginganimation.zip on android.

Thanks.

Gus.

Any pointing to an affective tutorial are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A thread from someone trying to do something similar: http://forum.samdroid.net/f42/change-samsung-turn-off-charging-animation-4924/

Answer (score 0):

you have to change one of the systems apps for that.

maybe [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1823223) can help

Comment: which one you think might be and there is an app for that or can Do that using simply update.zip or android sdk?

Comment: sorry, I mean there is a place where those files are in the android of a mtk6575 chinese tablet? BTW do you know how can I make a logo.bin?

Comment: where is that tutorial If you don't mind to point me to...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After your device was Rooted add the animation file to:

```
/system/media/charging
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can change its not a zip or location in system apps..

In mtk devices 
You can go to logo bin in there flashing file 
Extract logo bin 
And there you will find all images of battery

You can customize by using abode Photoshop or illustrator